# SQL -> LINQ (C#)

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have an SQL query (below) that essentially takes a student from tbStudents, and then gets the most recent term (a number, but stored as a string) in tbTerms.

There is a one-to-many relationship with a student in tbStudents to a term record in tbTerms. Example:

tbStudents:

```
StudentId FirstName LastName
12345     John      Smith
12346     Jane      Doe
```

tbTerms:

```
StudentId Term
12345     1234
12345     1235
12345     1236
12346     1233
12346     1234
```

Desired:

```
StudentId FirstName LastName Term
12345     John      Smith    1236
12346     Jane      Doe      1234
```

SQL Query:

```
select tbStudents.student_id, tbStudents.user_id, tbStudents.firstname, tbStudents.lastname, v.rTerm
    from  tbStudents
    inner join (
        select tbTerms.student_id, MAX(tbTerms.term) as rTerm
        from tbTerms
        group by tbTerms.student_id
    ) v on v.student_id = tbStudents.student_id
```

I've been trying to get this all into one LINQ statement, but I'm having trouble. Is there anyway to do this in one statement? Or must it be done in multiple statements. Thanks in advanced.

Edit: C# code of what I have tried.

```
var students = (from s in dockDb.tbStudents
                join t in dockDb.tbTerms on s.student_id equals t.student_id
                into pairs
                from p in pairs
                select new { UserId = s.user_id, StudentId = s.student_id, Term = p.term } ).ToList();
```

Output is similar to:

```
StudentId FirstName LastName Term
12345     John      Smith    1234
12345     John      Smith    1235
12345     John      Smith    1236
12346     Jane      Doe      1233
12346     Jane      Doe      1234
```

Edit #2: I'm using Entity Framework for data. I'm not sure if this affects anything, but most of the solutions are 'Syntactically incorrect' when I attempt them.

Comment: Can you show what you have already?

Comment: "syntatically incorrect". Call the extension AsEnumerable(). Then they will not be "syntatically incorrect".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be possible. Try this:

```
from s in Students
join t in Terms on t.StudentId = s.StudentId
select new {Student = s, Term = t}
group by s into g
select new {g.Key.StudentId, g.Key.FirstName, g.Key.LastName, g.Max(x=>x.Term.term)};
```

Breaking it down, the first two lines define the domain in which to search; namely, the inner-joined combination of Students and Terms, linked by StudentId. Each unique combination of Student and Term are put into an anonymous type, and then those instances are grouped by each unique Student into a Lookup (a read-only collection of IEnumerables referenced by key). The, we can select the key's (Student's) vital info, and in the list of terms, find the one with the highest value (which will be the most recent).

Comment: I had to modify some things in your code to make it run, but otherwise your structure was pretty much what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like that:

```
from s in dockDb.tbStudents
join t in dockDb.tbTerms on t.student_id equals s.student_id into st
group st by New {StudentID = st.student_id, Term = t.term} into g
select New { g.Key, g.Max(i => i.Term) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, I've always considered syntax with extension methods to be more readable and natural to write. So, here goes:

```
context.Students.Select(s => new
{
    s.StudentId,
    s.FirstName,
    s.LastName,
    Term = context.Terms.Where(t => t.StudentId == s.StudentId)
                        .Select(t => t.TermNumber)
                        .OrderByDescending(t => t)
                        .First()
});
```

Basically, for each student, it selects all his/her terms, orders them from most recent to least recent and includes first one (the most recent) in result.

Answer (score 0):

[Groupby](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) is your friend. Let us simply group the data by student id, then *project* it to a new form. This is a linqpad example:

```
void Main()
{
    var students = new List<Student>()
    {
      new Student() { StudentID = 12345, Name = "Smith" },
      new Student() { StudentID = 12346, Name = "Jones" }
      };

    var terms = new List<Term>()
    {
        new Term() { StudentID=12345, TermID = 1234 },
        new Term() { StudentID=12345, TermID = 1235 },
        new Term() { StudentID=12345, TermID = 1236 },
        new Term() { StudentID=12345, TermID = 1237 },
        new Term() { StudentID=12346, TermID = 1233 },
        new Term() { StudentID=12346, TermID = 1234 },
    };

    var result = terms.GroupBy (tm => tm.StudentID)
                      .Select (gr => new
    {
        Name = students.First (s => s.StudentID == gr.Key).Name,
        Terms = gr.Select (g => g.TermID)
    });


    result.Dump();

}

// Define other methods and classes here
    public class Student
    {
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Term
    {
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public int TermID { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the output which can be used:

[image]